# Placing and destroying blocks using Minecraft commands

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wanted to mess with some basic commands and one of the commands that I have heard of quite frequently was one that gives someone an item than can break and place entities, blocks or items.

I have looked at some ways to write it and I use this as an example for giving myself a block of stone that can be placed on a chest:

```
/give Steve stone{CanPlaceOn:["chest"]}
```

...but it ends up not working. Can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on PE the the command is:
`/give steve stone 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["chest"]}}`
or if on Java
`/give steve stone 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["chest"]}`

Comment: The syntax on PE is different from Java because since one of the updates PE changed from the NBT tag to having the Json component with java still having the simple NBT tag, it's stupid really

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was using the iOS Pocket version, which is probably why it didn't work.

Comment: Any pocket edition works as stated above, and no problem :D (i keep wanting to spell problem as problemb)